# How I can create this view in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Hi I have a database of a social network; users can submit content and comment it. They can join in groups. And I want to make some views:

View for users who write over 1,000 comments

```
CREATE VIEW userPro
AS SELECT U.nick, C.id 
FROM User.U, Comments.C 
WHERE C.id> 1000
```

¿¿¿ How I can put the 'Count' ??? (I need id count > 1000)

View for users who are in 3 different groups and sended more than 10 content

```
CREATE VIEW userGroupArt
AS SELECT U.nick, Co.id, G.idg
FROM  User.U, Content.Co, Group.G
WHERE COUNT BY(idg > 3 AND content >10)
```

I have a lot of difficult working with Count by but I read a lot of documentation. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should fix your joins before worrying about the count.

Comment: What column in `Comments` relates to `User`? What column in `Content` and `Group` relates to `User`?

Comment: It would help if you posted the structure of these 3 tables.

Comment: Hi Comments have "idc" and User "nick" for primary key      Content have "id", group "idg" and user "nick"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to learn more about [sql having clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
CREATE VIEW userPro
AS SELECT U.nick, C.id 
FROM `User` AS U INNER JOIN Comments AS C ON 
U.id = C.user_id
HAVING COUNT(C.id) > 1000;


CREATE VIEW userGroupArt
AS SELECT U.nick
FROM `User` AS U INNER JOIN Content AS Co ON U.id = Co.user_id 
INNER JOIN  UserGroup AS UG on UG.user_id = U.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UG.group_id) > 3 AND COUNT(DISTINCT Co.id) > 10
```

Also you need to clarify what fields you want from second view - if you want a list of unique users, you can't select id of user group or content, because user can have many groups and contents.